# Swift - Data not displayed properly when using tableView.dequeueReusableCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When certain buttons are pressed in the app, their name, start and end time that they were pressed are displayed in a `UITableView`.

This worked fine when using a custom `UITableViewCell` but after setting up `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` instead, the `UITableView` is showing the first cell as a white empty cell when it is meant to show data. If more data is added, the first input which wasn't visible is now shown but the last input is missing/hidden.

I have found similar questions and implemented what seemed the main culprit but it didn't work for me.

```
    timelineTableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    timelineScrollViewContainer.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    timelineTableView.contentOffset = .zero
```

I also tried to change the section height but to no avail either.

Worth mentioning that the data is not displaying properly in the `UITableView` but is still saving properly in the plist.

The `UITableView` is loaded during the `ViewDidLoad` as mentioned in other questions as it seems the issue of the error for some.

Doeanyonene have another solution? thanks for the help

**cellForRowAt method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView ==  timelineTableView {

       //let cell = TimelineCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40), title: "test", startTime: "test", endTime: "test", rawStart: "") // Used previously before using dequeueReusableCell

        var cell: TimelineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: timelineCellId, for: indexPath) as! TimelineCell

        if let marker = markUpPlist.arrayObjects.filter({$0.UUIDpic == endClipSelectedMarkerUUID}).first {
            cell = TimelineCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40), title: "test", startTime: "test", endTime: "test", rawStart: "")
            cell.backgroundColor = marker.colour
            cell.cellLabelTitle.text = marker.name
            cell.cellUUID.text = marker.UUIDpic

            if let timeline = chronData.rows.filter({$0.rowName == marker.name}).first {
                if let start = timeline.clips.last?.str {
                    cell.cellStartTime.text = chronTimeEdited(time: Double(start))
                    cell.cellStartRaw.text = String(start)
                }
                if let end = timeline.clips.last?.end {
                    cell.cellEndTime.text = chronTimeEdited(time: Double(end))
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
}
```

**TimelineCell.swift**

```
class TimelineCell : UITableViewCell {

var cellLabelTitle: UILabel!
var cellStartTime: UILabel!
var cellEndTime: UILabel!
var cellStartRaw: UILabel!
var cellUUID: UILabel!

init(frame: CGRect, title: String , startTime: String, endTime: String, rawStart: String) {
    super.init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "timelineCellId")

    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 29/255.0, green: 30/255.0, blue: 33/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    cellLabelTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    cellLabelTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellLabelTitle.textColor = UIColor.black

    addSubview(cellLabelTitle)

    cellLabelTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    cellLabelTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    cellLabelTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    cellLabelTitle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    cellStartTime = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    cellStartTime.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellStartTime.textColor = UIColor.black

    addSubview(cellStartTime)

    cellStartTime.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    cellStartTime.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    cellStartTime.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    cellStartTime.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellLabelTitle.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    cellEndTime = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    cellEndTime.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellEndTime.textColor = UIColor.black

    addSubview(cellEndTime)

    cellEndTime.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    cellEndTime.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    cellEndTime.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    cellEndTime.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellStartTime.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

    cellStartRaw = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    cellUUID = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    addSubview(cellStartRaw)
    addSubview(cellUUID)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
}
```

**Create tableview**

```
    timelineTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sideView.frame.width, height: sideView.frame.size.height)
    timelineTableView.delegate = self
    timelineTableView.dataSource = self
    timelineTableView.register(TimelineCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: timelineCellId)
    timelineTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    timelineTableView.separatorStyle = .none
    timelineTableView.backgroundColor = Style.BackgroundColor
    timelineTableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    timelineScrollViewContainer.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    timelineScrollViewContainer.addSubview(timelineTableView)
    timelineTableView.contentOffset = .zero
```

So recapitulating, using the line below shows the data properly  but the cells aren't reused properly.

```
 let cell = TimelineCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40), title: "test", startTime: "test", endTime: "test", rawStart: "")
```

Using the code below show a blank cell first and data not displayed properly but the cells are reused properly.

```
var cell: TimelineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: timelineCellId, for: indexPath) as! TimelineCell
```

Comment: Why does `cellForRowAt` use _both_ dequeueReusableCell _and_ create a new instance? You shouldn't use the c'tor directly at all. Why is there filtering in the `cellForRowAt` method - the model data should be filtered elsewhere and then the resulting array used to populate each row. Your cell is currently only populated when the filter condition is met.

Comment: From what I understand is that I am actually using the dequeueReusableCell wrong. How would you set up the dequeueReusableCell using using the custom TimelineCell if this isn't the correct way? I will look into improving the way i filter the array thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `cellForRowAt` to look like this. I'm guessing as to how your chronData structure relates to the source table, so it's mostly using your original logic.
You need to blank out fields that should be empty, as otherwise they will retain state as you scroll.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: TimelineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: timelineCellId, for: indexPath) as! TimelineCell

    let marker = markUpPListFiltered
    cell.backgroundColor = marker.colour
    cell.cellLabelTitle.text = marker.name
    cell.cellUUID.text = marker.UUIDpic
    if let timeline = chronData.rows.filter({$0.rowName == marker.name}).first {
       if let start = timeline.clips.last?.str {
           cell.cellStartTime.text = chronTimeEdited(time: Double(start))
           cell.cellStartRaw.text = String(start)
       }
       else
       {
           cell.cellStartTime.text = ""
           cell.cellStartRaw.text = ""
       }
       if let end = timeline.clips.last?.end {
           cell.cellEndTime.text = chronTimeEdited(time: Double(end))
       }          
       else
       {
           cell.cellEndTime.text = ""
       }
    }
    return cell
}
```

It assumes there is an array for your filtered sorted data called `markupPListFiltered`. Prepare this in `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else. You haven't shown the other datasource methods so I'll assume you can change these as needed, e.g.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
  return markupPListFiltered.count
}
```

`TimelineCell` needs the c'tor to have the data removed. You should consider using a storyboard to design your cells and link up the widgets with the outlets (see any of the hundreds of tutorials on table views, I'd recommend Ray Wenderlich as a good starter source).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will create a cell using the storyboard and test it.

Comment: I ended up editing my cell and removing the data in the UITableViewCell initialiser like you mentioned which worked and I didn't need to create the cell in the storyboard. Your answer pointed me in the right direction thanks again.